# rsyslog: Add sequential counter to log messages

Tags: sequence, counter, message, rsyslog

Due to unreliable protocol some log messages could be lost on the way to syslog server. In our case, syslog server persist messages to a DB.

We need a reliable way to see if there are messages lost and how many?

**Can you please offer me some tips?**

One possibility is to add a running counter to each message which increments by 1 for each. So by looking at the embedded counter value in the message, we could reliably detect the count of lost.

There is a [mmsequence module](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/mmsequence.html) , but it is marked deprecated and the page direct us to use global variable instead. But it does not indicate the name of this global variable.

Can someone please help with name of this global variable that substitutes mmsequence?